How to fix 'script returned exit code 1' when run Jenkins pipeline
I'm setting up a Jenkins pipeline to build a React application. The build command works fine on my local system, but when executed in the pipeline, it returns an error with exit code 1. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?
how to fix this issue?This is my pipeline script
enter image description here

Please provide the error logs that you see in the pipeline and which step is failing. According to your pipeline, either checkout git repo or installing npm packages. Most of cases you have checkout issue, then credentials of Jenkins is not provided or wrong name or so.

You should be able to see logs in Jenkins web interface. Either

under your failed job of your project (structured),
in administration submenu (long)

